# Tough time understanding the below Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and I am having a hard understanding the below code which prints all the prime numbers below 10.

```
N = 10                    
primes = []    
for n in range(2,N+1):                     
    for p in primes:          
        if n % p == 0: break        
    else:                       
        primes.append(n)            
print(primes)
```

My question is- what is the value of p during the first iteration? Isn't it 0? If so, n%p is always 0 right? Please help me understand.

Comment: You could… add a few `print` statements here and there to understand what this code does…?!

Comment: Its hard to see but that `else` looks like its part of the `for` loop, so it will first append 2, then start using the `if` conditional in the `for` loop on further iterations

Comment: The formatting of the code looks wrong. Make sure you correct it.

Comment: I've corrected the indentation with the assumption that it's `for..else`, since supposedly this code *is* working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for..in` loop over an empty list basically does nothing; it says "for each element in this list, do something", and since there is nothing in the list, it does nothing. So on the first iteration of the outer loop, the `for p in primes` does nothing at all, and the `else` clause is invoked.

On subsequent iterations there *is* something in `primes`, so the loop will get invoked and `p` will be populated with values.

The `else` clause of a `for..in` loop will be executed at the end of the loop, **unless the loop is interrupted by `break`.** That's exactly what is happening on your code: if the loop finds a divisible number, it `break`s the loop and nothing happens, otherwise the number will get added to `primes`.

The algorithm in a nutshell is: for numbers from 2…10, if the number is not a multiple of an already discovered prime, it's a prime.